# Splitting XML based on it content preserving Header

Tags: apache-camel

Is that possible with Camel to split following XML message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyOrder>
<header>
    ....
</header>
<body>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>10</itemNumber>
        <itemType>A</itemType>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>20</itemNumber>
        <itemType>B</itemType>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>30</itemNumber>
        <itemType>C</itemType>
    </item>
</body>     
</MyOrder>
```

to the following 3 parts :

**1)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyOrder>
<header>
    ....
</header>
<body>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>10</itemNumber>
        <itemType>A</itemType>
    </item>
</body>     
</MyOrder>
```

**2)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyOrder>
<header>
    ....
</header>
<body>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>20</itemNumber>
        <itemType>B</itemType>
    </item>
</body>     
</MyOrder>
```

**3)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyOrder>
<header>
    ....
</header>
<body>
    <item>
        <itemNumber>30</itemNumber>
        <itemType>C</itemType>
    </item>
</body>     
</MyOrder>
```

? Pay attention result is based on *itemType* tag and each message has Header that was not changed at all. Is Splitter EIP pattern can help here? Please share your thoughts here!

Comment: would you be interested in a piece of java code that does that splitting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes set the header first, and then do the splitting. As each splitted messages will have a copy of the headers from the parent message used for splitting.

Answer (score 0):

so If I understand you, you want to split the xml file by item node, group those nodes by type ( I suppose you can have several items of type A, B, C ... ) and generate another xml, one by item type ? 
Splitter can use xpath expression, so I think you can use it, if you already know all possible types.I don't know in that case if the splitter will give you one unique item node or a list of note matching the item type. You may have to use an agregator to put them back together.

However, I dont think you will have your header. you will probably need to put it back at the end of the process
Your requirement is a bit complex, splitter can surely help, but it won't be straightforward.

I found this : http://www.davsclaus.com/2011/11/splitting-big-xml-files-with-apache.html